# MongoDb BI connection issue

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to configure the MongoDB BI Connector.

I have installed mongodb-bi-win32-x86_64-v2.5.0.msi Mongodb version is 3.0.15

1.Started mongod

mongod --dbpath d:/data1 --auth

Started mongosqld
mongosqld --auth --mongo-username xxxx --mongo-password xxx --mongo-authenticationSource admin

I am getting the following error

E SAMPLER [schemaDiscovery] unable to initialize schema: error sampling collection: failed to execute aggregate: unrecognized fi eld 'readConcern'

Let me know how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your mongod version is too old... For 2.5 BI connector

As said [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-bi-connector-windows/)!

> The MongoDB Connector for BI and associated utilities are compatible
>   only with MongoDB server version 3.2 or greater.

Comment: yes. thats the mistake i guess. Thanks for the information